# how to make sure that there is no letter, that his occurrence ist't more than 4 in a string for a login system?

Tags: php

I want to know if there is a letter, that is in a string (name) more than 4.
I have the issue, that my example code is not correct, because when you write the name like that: aaaAA
it will say there is no error. Because the letters in the array are like this ("A","a",....).

i have another files for a index, Car Class. I want just to make test, that this function works. This function should find out, whether a letter be repeated more than 4 example:
aaaaa; the function should here say that is not allowed.
aaaAA; the function should here say that is not allowed.
Upper and lower case letters must be treated equally

Can i have some help?

thank you very much for all.

```
    public function checkLetterOccurence($newMarke)
    {
        //array of the letter
        $letterKette = array('A', 'a', 'B', 'b', 'C', 'c', 'D', 'd', 'E', 'e', 'F', 'f', 'G', 'g', 'H', 'h', 'I', 'i', 'J', 'j', 'K', 'k', 'L', 'l', 'M', 'm', 'N', 'n', 'O', 'o', 'P', 'p', 'Q', 'q', 'R', 'r', 'S', 's', 'T', 't', 'U', 'u', 'V', 'v', 'W', 'w', 'X', 'x', 'Y', 'y', 'Z', 'z');
        

        for ($i = 0; $i < count(  $letterKette); $i++) {

            if (substr_count($newMarke, $letterKette[i]) > 4) {
                echo "there is a letter that is more than 4 written, and that is not allowed.";
                die();
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Can you give some example input and expected output?

Comment: sure thank you.

i have another file for a index, Car Class.
I want just to make test, that this function works.
This function shoul find out, whether a letter be repeated more than 4  example:

aaaaa; the function should here say that is not allowed
aaaAA; the function should here say that is not allowed

Upper and lower case letters must be treated equally

Comment: Please update the question with those details.  Otherwise it will hard for us to help you.

Answer (score 2):

You have to make your input all-lowercase and then count occurrence of letters:

```php
<?php

$input = 'aaaAA';

function checkLetterOccurence($input) {
    $input = strtolower($input);
    // Split text to array of letters, e.g. "hello" becomes ["h", "e", "l", "l", "o"]
    $input = str_split($input);
    
    // Here we will keep map of letters and how much time it appears in word
    $count = [];
    
    foreach ($input as $letter) {
        // If there is no such letter added yet, we add new one with initial value 0. Next line will add +1 to it
        $count[$letter] ??= 0; // Or if (!isset($count[$letter])) $count[$letter] = 0;
        $count[$letter]++;
    }
    
    // Filter only those letters that appear more than 4 times in word 
    $filteredInput = array_filter($count, fn($c) => $c > 4);
    
    // If we have +4 same letter in word - write out error message
    if (!empty($filteredInput)) {
        echo "There is a letter that is more than 4 written, and that is not allowed. Wrong letters: " . implode(',', array_keys($filteredInput));
    } else {
        echo "All good";
    }
}

checkLetterOccurence('aaaAA');
```

[Example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c2821359f98a6b8e60470b3039eac5e5501fd035)

Comment: 1.why did you convert $ input to array    ( $input = str_split($input);  ).

2.  why did you write that     $count = [];

3. i did't understand that  $count[$letter] ??=0   .

4.  i did't understand that    $filteredInput = array_filter($count, fn($c) => $c > 4);
i would be grateful if you can explain your code

Comment: 1. To work with single letter. 2. Initialize final map of letters and frequency. 3. Initialize letter with 0 count. 4. Filter all letters to leave only ones that appears in word more than 4 times